# ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException

Tags: java, json

I get the below exception even after having json.jar and commons-collections.jar in classpath. It fails exactly at the import statement for `JSONException`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:191)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:111)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:509)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
... 30 more
```

Comment: Are you sure above jar is on classpath? Version correct?

Comment: open the json.jar you have, and look for the class `org.json.JSONException`

Comment: @SajanChandran It exists in the jar.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a runtime error, not a compile error, so the build path probably doesn't help you.  Do you have those jars in your classpath?  That's what's used at runtime to find classes.

Comment: This question helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956156/websphere-classnotfoundexception-with-deployed-dynamic-web-project?rq=1

Comment: I had to add the jar to web module's classpath, i.e, WEB-INF/lib. I did this by selecting the jar from Web Libraries in Java EE Module dependencies, and so it overrides the MANIFEST classpath which is not cooperative with json

Answer (score 1):

Put your JAR libraries into the WEB-INF/lib folder.